# Android 2.3.5 device shows only 8 languages - are the rest there?

Tags: android

My company has an Android app which has translations for Portuguese for the various layouts and resource when the device is set to a Portuguese locale.

But I was testing it on one of the intended target devices (a stock out-of-the-box Samsung Media Player 4.0 running Android 2.3.5), and when I go to Settings>Select Locale, Portuguese is not one of the options! It only shows 8 - a few flavors of English and French, German, Italian, Spanish and Korean, and that's it!

Supposedly Gingerbread supports 57 locales - how do I set its locale to something other than the above 8?   If I set it programmatically are all the other languages already in the OS, but just not exposed by the device manufacturer?

Thanks in advance.